# Nest.js - skip middleware based on header value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I have an application which uses `nestjs` and `MiddlewareConsumer`.
I would like to know if there's a way to skip a middleware based on a header value?

I checked documentation and saw that I can only use path or method (as I do now) but maybe there's something I'm missing?

Sample of my code:

```
export class AuthorizationModule implements NestModule {
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(DiscriminatorValidator).with(common.USERS).forRoutes(
        {path: RELATIVE_RESOURCE_PATH, method: RequestMethod.POST},{path: RELATIVE_RESOURCE_PATH, method: RequestMethod.PUT});
    consumer.apply(validate).forRoutes(AuthorizationController);
    consumer.apply(HeadersValidator).with().forRoutes(AuthorizationController);
    consumer.apply(ContextAndHeadersMiddleware).forRoutes(AuthorizationController);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with the `MiddlewareConsumer`.

---

However, the middleware itself can check if its applicable or should be skipped:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContextAndHeadersMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    if (req.get('my-header') === 'SKIP') {
      // skip this middleware if header value is set
      return next();
    }
    // middleware logic
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the internal check, but I wanted to avoid that.